# SharePoint 2013 test logged in User

Tags: c#, authentication, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I developed a WebPart in SharePoint 2013 and I have to create a function called IsLoggedInUser()
that return false if the login user is anonymous and true otherwise.

Can someone helps me?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You will need to add some code to show what you have tried. Also are you talking about C# and server side code?

Comment: Sory i don't create the function yet. i work on FBAMembership Provider with aspnetdb.
My destination is to Know the status of Logged User, that function determine if the login user is anonymous or else.
I work with c# and server side code

Comment: this.Context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated

Answer (score 1):

```
if (SPContext.Current.Web.CurrentUser != null)
    return true;
```

Comment: It's best to add some explanation about what the problem was rather than just provide a line of code (also, please format code appropriately).

Comment: i am trying to add try statement with some comments but the site is giving a not will formatted code

Comment: Indent all of your code by 4 spaces and separate it from text you add by an empty line